# Tutorial or tips needed to perform a set of web admin tasks using Selenium(Beginner level query)

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm looking at a few pointers /a tutorial or maybe even another question to help me with my task. I'm looking to automate a web admin task. What I would like to do is :

1. Login to an application.
2. Navigate to a particular menu.
3. Search for a particular item through a search bar.
4. If the item is displayed in the search items then click on a set of buttons on the UI and proceed with the task.
5. If the item is not displayed in the search results then continue searching till the item is displayed , and then perform step 4.

I have been able to perform up to step 3 using the selenium IDE plugin for Firefox. But I'm not quite sure how to proceed and where to incorporate the logic for steps 4 and 5. Do I use a programming language?(If yes, then how?)

Comment: What is step 3? The easiest way is to use the IDE, but this is not the most reliable or maintainable way to do it. You can either keep your scripts in an HTML format (which the IDE reads), or convert them into a programming language. Two common scenarios are using it with C# & Nunit, or TestNG and Java.

Answer (score 2):

You hit the limits of the IDE pretty quickly. The IDE doesn't incorporate logic, but it is good for quick and dirty automation tasks, figuring out locator id's, and helping people learn the basics of selenium. I would suggest checking out learning how to script in Selenium Webdriver. Documentation: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html

So for example if you're using Java (this was stolen from the documentation):

```
public class Selenium2Example  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");;

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("Cheese!");

        //Pseudocode
        if(element.isDisplayed()){
           // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element
           element.submit();
        }
        else{
        // Check the title of the page
           System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        }

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("cheese!");
            }
        });

        // Should see: "cheese! - Google Search"
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I dont quite understand whether you are trying to say whether I can find a solution using Selenium or not .Could you please elaborate?

Comment: sure, the selenium IDE plugin is just one part of selenium. The code that undergirds the IDE is actually what selenium is: a collection of API's to interact with the web browser. There are two variants selenium RC (Selenium 1) (which the IDE uses) and Selenium 2 which is the newest and arguably best variant. What I sent you was a bunch of sample code that is actually happening on the backend that causes selenium to interact with the web browser. It's like you said the IDE has limitations, and if you want to overcome them you have to start coding. Read the documentation; its fairly helpful.